# How to solve this non-linear equations?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum of the function $f(x,y)=xy$ in respect of the curve $x^4+y^4=32$.

Well
I defined Lagrange function
$L(x,y,\lambda)=xy+\lambda(x^4+y^4-32)$
Then

$L'_x=y+4\lambda x^3=0$

$L'_y=x+4\lambda y^3=0$

$L'_{\lambda}=x^4+y^4-32=0$

However, I have difficulty solving this system.
Can you please suggest a way to solve this non-linear system?

Comment: Just substitute $y=-4\lambda x^3$ into the other two equations. If $x$ is real, then the second equation gives $x=0$ or $4\lambda x^2=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $xy\neq 0 $ and also $\lambda \neq 0$ then from the first two equations we obtain:

- $y+4\lambda x^3=0 \implies y = -4\lambda x^3$
- $x+4\lambda y^3=0 \implies x = -4\lambda y^3$

and dividing term by term:

$$\frac x y = \frac{x^3}{y^3} \implies x^4=y^4 \implies |x|=|y|$$

and finally from the third equations we obtain:

$$2x^4 = 32 \implies x=\pm 2$$

As an alternative we can plug $y=\sqrt[4]{32-x^4}$ in the original function to obtain:

$$g(x) = f(x,y)= x\sqrt[4]{32-x^4}$$

and study $g'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the easiest way is to bring the terms with $\lambda$ on the RHS.

$y+4\lambda x^3=0\Rightarrow y-4\lambda x^3 \qquad (1)$

$x+4\lambda y^3=0\Rightarrow x-4\lambda y^3 \qquad (2)$

Next we exclude the case $x=y=0$ for the next steps.

Dividing (1) by (2) gives

$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x^3}{y^3}\Rightarrow y^4=x^4$. Inserting the expression for $x^4$ into the third FOC (first order condition).

$$x^4+x^4-32=0\Rightarrow x^4=16$$

This gives 2 real numbers for $x$. I think you can go on by yourself.